# How to validate URL param with AJV in Fastify?

Tags: schema, fastify, ajv

I'm trying to validate the URL param `verificationToken`, the issue is that the reply is always `Verification token is required.` as if the token is not provided in the URL.

```js
export const UserActivationSchema = {
    schema : {
       querystring: {
          type                : 'object',
          required            : [ 'verificationToken' ],
          additionalProperties: false,
          properties          : {
             verificationToken: {
                type: 'string'
             },
          },
          errorMessage        : {
             properties: {
                verificationToken: 'Verification token is required.'
             },
             required: 'Verification token is required.'
          }
       },
    },
    handler: activateEmail,
}
```

The route:

```js
fastify.get( '/activate/:verificationToken', UserActivationSchema );
```

I need to verify the `verificationToken` it is a string and provided in the URL.

Any idea how to fix this?

I'm trying to verify the `verificationToken` is a string and provided in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url in that syntax defines a path parameter and it is not a query string parameter.

You must change the schema property `querystring` to `params`.

Comment: Yes, this is the missing thing, thanks.